# Admin Consent failed for AAD application

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-ad-b2c

I have global adminstrator permission and When i try to do admin consent to AAD Application permissions i am getting below error.

`az : ERROR: Bad Request({"ClassName":"Microsoft.Portal.Framework.Exceptions.ClientException","Message":"Graph call failed with  httpCode=BadRequest, errorCode=Request_BadRequest, errorMessage=The application needs access to a service that your organization  aadb2c01 has not subscribed to. Please contact your administrator to review the configuration of your service  subscriptions. At line:141 char:13`
`+             az ad app permission admin-consent --id "$($app.Id)"`

After some research i found when spn(created in protal) is avaiable for application i can able to provide admin consent without the above error. I want to use powershell script to do admin consent

Used commands to create AAD application:
`New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "test"`

Admin consent:
`az ad app permission admin-consent --id "$($app.Id)"`

Need solution to do admin consent

Comment: Are you creating Azure AD App in which tenant (Azure AD/Azure AD B2C)?

Comment: Read the error : The application needs access to a service that your organization  aadb2c01 has not subscribed to. Please contact your administrator to review the configuration of your service  subscriptions

Comment: I am trying in Azure AD B2C @Rukmini

Comment: @jdweng , as  i mentioned when i create spn to my app in portal then the issue resolve. So its not related to the access as per my knowledge

Comment: The error message says you have not subscribed.  You can't get something you didn't pay for.

Comment: I tried in my environment and got it working like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/6xaKQTs.png) and in the Portal Admin consent is granted for the [**API permissions**](https://i.imgur.com/wGdVF0V.png). And check if the B2C tenant is configured properly

Comment: @vamsikrishnaparuchuri, I believe when you use wizard in the portal, it creates both an Application and a Service Principal. So, if you want to create the same in PowerShell, then you might need to use `New-AzureADApplication` and `New-AzureADServicePrincipal`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals

"If you register an application in the portal, an application object and a service principal object are automatically created in your home tenant. If you register/create an application using the Microsoft Graph APIs, creating the service principal object is a separate step."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

```
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "ruktest"

az login --allow-no-subscriptions
az ad app permission admin-consent --id AppId
```

[image]

By using the above commands, **Admin consent got granted successfully to the API permissions** like below:

[image]

**To resolve the error**, check the below:

I agree with @*mikesh*, make sure that the ***Azure Service Principal exists for the Azure AD Application you have created***. If not, create the Service Principal by using below command:

```
Connect-AzureAD

New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AccountEnabled $true -AppId AppID -AppRoleAssignmentRequired $true -DisplayName $App -Tags {WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp}
```

[image]

To  **`Connect-AzureAD`**, make sure you are connecting with the user which exists in Azure AD B2C tenant and has Global Administrator role assigned:

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, try recreating the Azure AD Application and check.

**Reference:**

[Apps & service principals in Azure AD - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals?tabs=browser#application-registration)

Answer (score 0):

As @mikesh mentioned in comments, when we use wizard in the portal, it creates both an Application and a Service Principal. So, if you want to create the same in PowerShell, then we need to use New-AzureADApplication and New-AzureADServicePrincipal both

```
$myapp=New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "myapp"
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId $B2CTenantId -Credential $creds
New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "$($myapp.AppId)"
```

After creating spn for myapp can able to do admin consent without any issue.